# How to add custom colors to specific arcs in donut charts in d3?

Tags: svg, d3.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to build a donut chart. How can i add different colors that are specific to an arc.  For example i want red color for status "one", blue for status "two" , green for status "three" and so on...

I tried the following,

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .domain(["one","two","three","four","five"])
 .range(["#013ADF", "#ACFA58", "#DF3A01", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"]);


paths.enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {console.log(color(d.name)); return color(d.name); })
```

I was able to get the colors initially. But when any status count was reduced to 0 , the colors gets shuffled. And again when i increased the status count, i was not able to get the specific color back...

Please Help with some suggestions....

Comment: What does the console log say? Does the `color` function work if you call it manually?

Comment: @ Lars Kotthoff color(d.name) in the console returns correct color codes initially.. But when any of my count value of the status reduces to zero and increased again, the problem arises and my color gets shuffled... Any solution???

Comment: What do you mean by "color gets shuffled"? Are you modifying `color` dynamically? How do you get the status counts?

Comment: Initially i assume red color to status "one", but when the status count is reduced to zero , the red color gets assigned to other statuses . . . Im not altering my color after it has been initialized

Comment: What is the status count and how does it relate to the colours? I can't see it in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better update the color every time not ONLY in enter().

```
paths.enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)

path.attr("fill", function(d, i) {console.log(color(d.name)); return color(d.name); })
```